# Get a content edit URL as a string without UrlHelpers or Orchard tokens

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I'm trying to get the edit URL of a content as a string from backend, the catch is I'm inside a workflow activity, so I can't use Url.Action... or Url.ItemEditLink... or other UrlHelpers as if it were a controller or a view. Also, although I'm inside a workflow, the contents I need it for are not part of the workflowContext or the activityContext, so I can't use those or tokens either.

A solution could be to get the content metadata and the site baseUrl and try to build it manually, but I think this way is prone to errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the URLs in the body of an e-mail message?

Comment: Yes, but the contents of which I need the Urls are not part of the workflow or the current context, so there are no tokens available. I have an activity that's basically the same as the email activity, but I need to create the body from backend and include the Urls there.

Comment: I have not personally done this, so I can't provide a complete answer, but maybe you can use a custom Token to fetch the content item you want and chain it with the existing EditUrl and AbsoluteUrl Tokens. http://arkleseizure.net/custom-tokens-in-orchard-cms

Comment: Is the issue that you cannot retrieve the ID of the content item or that you cannot create a UrlHelper in the activity? I was able to inject a RequestContext dependency and instantiate the UrlHelper, but the content ID came from a custom activity's tokens earlier in the workflow.

Comment: Thanks, I already have the contents Ids but need to generate the edit Url, so Im gonna try like you did. You could post as an answer if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I build a Uri in an activity:

```
public class MyClass : Task
{
    private readonly RequestContext _requestContext;
    ...

    public MyActivity(RequestContext requestContext, ...)
    {
        _requestContext = requestContext;
        ...
    }

    ...

    public override IEnumerable<LocalizedString> Execute(WorkflowContext workflowContext, ActivityContext activityContext)
    {
        var content = ... get using ID
        var helper = new UrlHelper(_requestContext);
        var baseurl = new Uri(_orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentSite.BaseUrl);
        Uri completeurl = new Uri(baseurl, helper.ItemDisplayUrl(content));

        yield return T("Done");
    }
}
```

Turns out that I actually do build the Uri semi-manually, but I haven't had issues with this method. You may be able to use just the ItemDisplayUrl for navigation inside of Orchard; I had to get the full URL because the string gets sent to an outside program (Slack).